# Showing that $S^1 \not\cong (0, 1)$ and $\not\cong [0, 1]$

Tags: general-topology

So far, I have shown that $S^1 \setminus \{(1, 0)\}$ *is homeomorphic* to $(0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$:

Define the function $f: S^1 \setminus \{(1, 0)\} \rightarrow (0, 1)$ by $f\big((\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))\big) = \theta / (2\pi)$ (since each point $(x, y) \subset S^1 $ may be represented uniquely by $x = \cos(\theta)$ and $y = \sin(\theta)$). By definition of trigonometric parameterization, each $(x, y) \in S^1$ may be uniquely represented by $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ such that $x = \cos(\theta)$ and $y = \sin(\theta)$. Then, each $\theta$ is scaled by a factor of $1/(2\pi)$ so that each $\theta$ corresponds to a unique point in the interval $(0, 1)$. Therefore, $f$ is injective. Next, given some $a \in (0, 1)$, we have the corresponding point $(x, y) \in S^1$ where $x = \cos(2\pi a)$, $y = \sin(2\pi a)$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

Next, let $U \subseteq S^1 \setminus \{(1, 0)\}$ be an open arc in $S^1$. That is, $U = (\theta_1, \theta_2)$ where $0 < \theta_1 < \theta_2 < 2\pi$. Then we have
$$f(U) = \left\{\frac{\vartheta}{2\pi} \ : \ \vartheta \in (\theta_1, \theta_2)\right\} = \left(\frac{\theta_1}{2\pi}, \frac{\theta_2}{2\pi}\right),$$
which is open in $(0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the subspace topology. Conversely, suppose $V \subseteq (0, 1)$ is an open interval in $(0, 1)$. That is, $V = (a, b)$ such that $0 < a < b < 1$. Then we have
$$f^{-1}(V) = \{(\cos(2\pi y), \sin(2\pi y)) \ : \ y \in (a, b)\} = (\cos(2\pi a), \sin(2\pi b)),$$
which is open in $S^1 \setminus \{(1, 0)\}$.
With all of these conditions shown, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

How can I go about showing that adding the point $(1, 0)$ to $S^1$ is troublesome and makes it not homeomorphic to $(0, 1)$ or $[0, 1]$? Can I somehow use the fact that I have shown above? It feels much more difficult since you must show there *does not* exist a bijective continuous function from $S^1 \rightarrow (0, 1)$ whose inverse is also continuous... any hints appreciated. **By the way**: I would like to try to prove this without the idea of compactness :).

Comment: Thank you. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) is some information for you about the way (and by whom) questions get closed. Can you please give me the link to the question posted last week you mentionned?

Comment: Clearly, your $f$ is a bijection and $f^{-1}$ is continuous. But you did not prove that $f$ is. You only defined "open arcs" in $X=S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\}$, as sets of the form $f^{-1}(a;b)$ with $0<a<b<1$, without proving that they were open subsets of $X$ (with its subspace topology from $\Bbb R^2$), in order to deduce that $f$ is continuous. This is not so easy, and [most posts on MSE about this homeomorphism](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24S%5E1%5Csetminus%5C%7B(1%2C0)%5C%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ahomeomorphic&p=1) don't either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple argument that doesn't use the fundamental group is as follows:

Suppose there is an homeomorphism $f$ between $(0,1)$ and $S^1$ (the same works for $[0,1]$).

Then, $g: (0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1)\to S^1\backslash \{f(1/2)\}$ given by $g(x)=f(x)$ would be an homeomorphism too. But $(0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1)$ is not connected (as the only connected sets in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals) and $S^1\backslash \{f(1/2)\}$ **is** connected (which can easily be proved showing it is path-connected, leaved as an exercise). But this is a contradiction, since homeomorphisms preserve connectedness.

Thus, there cannot exist any homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ or $[0,1]$ and $S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

For any real $a<b$, $[a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ are all contractible so their fundamental group or if you prefer homology groups is $0$. But, $H_1(\mathbb{S}^1)=\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1)=\mathbb{Z}$. With regards to the homeomorphism you construct, observe that there is an simpler method. Let $N$ be any point on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Stereographic projection sais that $\mathbb{S}^1-N$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$S^{1}$ isn't simply connected but both the two intervals are, so no homeomorphism can exists.